What is the purpose of parent_plan_handle in sys.dm_exec_cached_plans?
I am attempting to prove whether the plan cache is caching statements individually within multiple stored procedures with identical statements. I thought I would be able to use parent_plan_handle to see this relationship however it is always returning null.
I've checked this on both SQL 2019 and 2022.
When I consult the literature, the column is strangely absent.
The question: What is the purpose of parent_plan_handle in sys.dm_exec_cached_plans?

parent_plan_handle is undocumented. There is no official purpose. It would not work for you here.

I am attempting to prove whether the plan cache is caching statements individually within multiple stored procedures with identical statements.

In general, plans for identical statements in different stored procedures cannot be shared or reused*.
When you write a stored procedure, you are taking responsibility for parameterisation and plan reuse.
I mention parameterisation because neither simple nor forced parameterisation function within a procedure.
As a starting point, you should think of each module you write as a unit of plan reuse.

* There are a few technical exceptions to this. The most obvious one is where one stored procedure calls another. Clearly a cached plan for the nested procedure might be reused. Similarly, EXEC (string) or sys.sp_executesql within a stored procedure presents an opportunity for plan reuse. Each submits a new batch to SQL Server, which is evaluated for plan reuse.
